# Need my 'enemyBall' variable instances with function scope, to be made accessible outside

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

So basically, I have a function `spawnEnem()` that spawns the enemy and runs the code at certain intervals using `NSTimer`. I also have a contact function that handles all the contact between objects in my game. In the other function `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`, I try to call upon my `enemyBall` variable instantiated inside `spawnEnem()` but for obvious reason it can't grab it. I have declared the `enemyBall` instance inside `spawnEnum()` as I need to create and process new instances of it every time the function is called. Anyway to get the `enemyBall` instance to travel beyond the function it's in?

**SpawnEnem Function**

```
@objc func spawnEnem() {

        let enemyBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyBall")


        self.addChild(enemyBall)
        enemyBall.size = CGSize(width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
        enemyBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyBall.size.width/2)
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true


        // Physics of our enemy
        enemyBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyBall.size.width / 2)
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.EnemyHere // setting enemyBall to our physics
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.smallBall | PhysicsCatagroy.mainBall 
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.smallBall | PhysicsCatagroy.mainBall 
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false // we dont want enemy effected by gravity
        enemyBall.name = "Enemy"
}
```

**didBegin contact function**

```
       func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode


           if ((firstBody.name == "Enemy") && (secondBody.name == "smallBall")) {

            NSLog("ENEMY & SMALL Ball TOUCHED!")
            let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: Emitter.enemyDead)!
            emitter.zPosition = 4
            emitter.targetNode = self
            emitter.position = enemyBall.position // ERROR IS HERE
            enemyBall.removeFromParent() // ERROR IS HERE
            addChild(emitter)

            collisonOnSmallBall(enemyBall: firstBody, smallBall: secondBody)

           } else if ((firstBody.name == "smallBall") && (secondBody.name == "Enemy")){
               score+=1
               NSLog("SMALL BALL & ENEMY TOUCHED!\(score)")
               collisonOnSmallBall(enemyBall: secondBody, smallBall: firstBody)
           } else if ((firstBody.name == "mainBall") && (secondBody.name == "Enemy")) {
               lives-=1
               NSLog("MAINBALL & ENEMY TOUCHED! \(lives)")

           }

       }
```

I've been trying a lot to fix it, and I've had no luck. It seemed like a simple issue but turns out it's not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode


       if ((firstBody.name == "Enemy") && (secondBody.name == "smallBall")) {

        NSLog("ENEMY & SMALL Ball TOUCHED!")
        let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: Emitter.enemyDead)!
        emitter.zPosition = 4
        emitter.targetNode = self
        emitter.position = firstBody.position // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< LOOK
        firstBody.removeFromParent() // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< LOOK
        addChild(emitter)

        collisonOnSmallBall(enemyBall: firstBody, smallBall: secondBody)

       } else if ((firstBody.name == "smallBall") && (secondBody.name == "Enemy")){
           score+=1
           NSLog("SMALL BALL & ENEMY TOUCHED!\(score)")
           collisonOnSmallBall(enemyBall: secondBody, smallBall: firstBody)
       } else if ((firstBody.name == "mainBall") && (secondBody.name == "Enemy")) {
           lives-=1
           NSLog("MAINBALL & ENEMY TOUCHED! \(lives)")

       }

   }
```

Hope this helps, let me know how you get on.

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ran into a new issue and I can't seem to fix it.

Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

"Moving the instruction pointer can result in unexpected behavior, including crashing your application."

This is on this line of code        **let enemyBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyBall")**

Comment: Hi Drafter, you need to post a new question. If the first answer helped please upmark the answer and click the tick if it answered your question.

Comment: You can always up mark the answer too. Its kinda polite to do so if it helped.